# How would you sanitize the URLs in this function?

Tags: php, url, output, sanitize

I am new to PHP and having a hard time trying to sanitize the output that this function creates. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Function is below:

```
function getTemplateBreadcrumbs($path, $title){

  $path = str_replace("/", "/", $path);

  $breadcrumbs = "<ul>\n";
  $breadcrumbs .= "  <li><a href=\"/\">Home</a></li>\n";

  $directories = explode("/", $path);
  $tempPath = "/";

  for($x=1; $x < count($directories)-2; $x++){
    if($directories[$x] != null){

      $tempPath .= $directories[$x] . "/";

      $linkText = getPageVariable("pageTitle", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $tempPath . "index.php");
      if($linkText == null){
        $linkText = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $directories[$x]));
      }

      $breadcrumbs .= "  <li><a href=\"" . $tempPath . "\">$linkText</a></li>\n";
    }
  }

  $breadcrumbs .= "  <li>" . $title . "</li>\n";
  $breadcrumbs .= "</ul>\n";

  return $breadcrumbs;
}
```

Comment: sanitize for what? You have to sanitize for the environment the data's going to be used in. sanitization is not something you can sprinkle on data like salt on food.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) with the [`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

```
$url = filter_var($tempPath , FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Comment: you got the link right, then your code says `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`

Comment: @DigitalChris oops. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much. The FILTER_SANITIZE_URL fixed the issue I was having. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

u can debug using `echo`, `print_r()`, `var_dump()`
I use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($var));
```

example of how you can use:

```
function getTemplateBreadcrumbs($path, $title){

  //rest of the code
  echo '<pre>';
  echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($breadcrumbs));
  echo '</pre>';
  return $breadcrumbs;
}
```

if you want to test from another part of the code:

```
$teste = getTemplateBreadcrumbs('/home/index', 'Home Page');
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($teste));
echo '</pre>';
```